# Install Django using pip from bash

Tags: django, bash, installscript

I am trying to write an install script for my project which requires Django.  I am using pip to install a list of apps but when it gets to Django it says

```
    You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.  
    Would you like to create one now?
```

I need this script to be autonomous.

Is there away to automatically answer this question or ignore it and set the superusers later?

My basic bash script looks something like this

```
    #!/bin/bash

    set -eux

    #==================================================#
    # These should be just the server requirements only 
    # !! Exception being scipy for now. pip install not 
    # working
    #==================================================#

    apt-get install -y python postgresql-9.1 apache2 python-setuptools postgresql-server-dev-9.1 postgresql-9.1-postgis postgis python-scipy binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin git

    #==================================================#
    # setup the posgis template for postgresql
    #==================================================#
    GEOGRAPHY=0
    POSTGIS_SQL=postgis.sql

    BLAH BLAH !!!
    Lots of database set up code here

   #==================================================#
   # Setup the python environment
   #==================================================#
   easy_install virtualenv
   easy_install virtualenvwrapper
   easy_install pip

   #==================================================#
   # Pull the catami code from git and install 
   #==================================================#

   mkdir -p /home/catami
   mkdir -p /home/catami/catamiportal
   cd /home/catami/catamiportal
   git clone https://github.com/catami/catami.git
   cd catami

   pip install -r requirements.txt

   python manage.py syncdb

   manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I am getting grief from installing django from the requirements file.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake.  it is the syncdb command that is asking the question not the install.

The solution is

```
    python manage.py syncdb --noinput
```